# Restarting network service on a live server

Tags: networking

Is it safe restarting the network service using

```
sudo service networking restart
```

on a server with more than 1k concurrent active users on a tcp program?

the reason why I need to restart is because I added a new failover ip and want it to be in use

Answer (score 0):

Worked fine if it helps anyone